# How to remove these pesky extra spaces

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The top widget on my wordpress [page](http://bit.ly/HXNHYq) shows a height property when I check it with chrome developer tools, and that height adds extra spaces on top and bottom of the widget (shown in yellow on the attached picture).

I've been trying for many hours to change or remove that height attribute, but I cant find where it is originated from and how to deal with it.

Please help!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you have a lot of `&#8203;` unicode sequences before and after your element in the source code causing all that unwanted space. (they are visible using firebug)

[image: unicode sequences]

you cannot perceive them in the source code, because that character is the 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' `(U+200B)`

Comment: I am checking the page source but don't see any '&#8203;', I also removed all possible spaces in widget editing window in wordpress, other widgets don't have this problem and they were created the same way

Comment: Are special characters you cannot see (they are special spaces) you introduced in some way (maybe due to a copy'n paste operation). look them in firebug and try to modify the source code from there, removing those sequences.

Comment: so how do I get rid of them? This is a text widget, and many others I have don't have this problem :(

Comment: a workaround is set `#textwidget` height ~ to 132px so you would remove the extra space at the bottom (but of course you should use it as last resort)

Comment: I pasted the code from jsfiddle, however now I tried to clean the code through pasting it in notepad and then coping it from there again, but it didnt help. I also tried to make another widget with same content but it has the same problem.

Comment: I tried the workaround and it didn't help.. the only way is to get rid of those special characters now

Answer (score 1):

you can remove them with regex. js:

```
HTML = HTML.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '');
```

c#

```
hVal = Regex.Replace(hVal, "[\\u200B-\\u200D\\uFEFF]", "");
```