# Remove Hidden &#8203;

Tags: html, unicode, notepad++, dreamweaver, hidden-characters

I have a simple HTML snippet that I copy and pasted into Dreamweaver. For some reason during the copy and paste, I picked up this weird `&#8203;` character that doesn't render in Notepad++ or Dreamweaver but it causes a line break in the browser.

I can't seem to get rid of it or even see it in a text editor.

Does anyone know how to remove this?

**CODE**

[image]

**Chrome Console**

[image]

Comment: `&#8203;` stands for U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE, which indicates an *optional* line breaking point. It is difficult so see what possible harm it could do at the start of a block. But it *can* of course be removed using a good editor like Babelpad. This does doesn’t sound like being on-topic at SO.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that it is causing a line break right before the image. Which is not what I want. I was able to remove it through the Dreamweaver live preview window but the characters didn't show up in the code.

Comment: this javascript answer will do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string -  there is also a firebug solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015411/how-to-remove-these-pesky-extra-spaces/10015524#10015524